# React handle select drop down with table scroll

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-select, reactstrap

Here in my react application I am using **reactstrap** table. Inside the table, I am using **react-select/async** for dropdown. 
When I am typing in the **react-select/async** options should come over the table if it has more options. For over the **react-select/async** I have defined another **div** and set position for that **div**.

```
<div style={this.state.isAsyncSelectOpen ? { position: 'absolute', width: '190px' }:{}}> 
  ....
</div>
```

Inside the div I have written async select.
[image]

So I can get the above output. But the problem is when scrolling horizontally while async select shows options at the time the entire div also scrolls.

Output
[image]

Below I have given my code as references.

```
<div style={this.state.isAsyncSelectOpen ? { position: 'absolute', width: '190px' }:{}}>
    <Field
      name={`tests[${index}].testing_method`}
      component={AsyncSelectInput}
      selectedValue={this.state.testing[index].option}
      placeholder="Search"
      validate={testField}
      menuIsOpen={this.state.testing[index].menuIsOpen}
      isClearable={this.state.testing[index].testingClearable}
      openLoad={(input: string, callback: any) =>{
      this.onSelectOpen(input);
      this.loadTesting(input, callback, index)
        }}
      searchByName={(e: any) => this.searchTestingByName(e, index)}
      onMenuClose={()=>{
         this.setState({isAsyncSelectOpen: false});
      }}
      />
      <Field
      name={`tests[${index}].test_id`}
      component={ReduxFormInput}
      type="hidden"
     />                            
   </div>
```

And I have set style conditionally when async select shows its options. At the time the only style applied.

Below I have given code how I handled the changing styles.

```
onSelectOpen = (inputValue:string)=>{
    if(size(inputValue) > 0){
      this.setState({isAsyncSelectOpen: true});
    }else{
      this.setState({isAsyncSelectOpen: false});
    }
  }
```

And have tried another one approach also, possible handle **reactstrap** table scroll event. But I could not. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: what is doing `size(inputValue)` ?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii ```size(inputValue)```  is checking length is greater than 0 or not. If it is greater then 0 I update isAsyncSelectOpen to true or isAsyncSelectOpen to false.

Answer (score 1):

Try these props in `react-select` if it's useful.

**closeMenuOnScroll**

> If true, close the select menu when the user scrolls the document/body.

**menuShouldBlockScroll**

> boolean = false
>
> Whether to block scroll events when the menu is open

Also, see other props and go thru the doc for more details:

https://react-select.com/props

Comment: I have those props it does not help me. Now I assume we can handle in the reactstrap table scroll event. When we stroll at the we change the position.